# Null key error while setting up custom Chocolatey package

Tags: null, chocolatey

I'm trying to create a custom Chocolatey package that will use an msi file from a file share and I'm receiving the error below. I've be able to troubleshoot most of the error during this process, but I can't figure this one out.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue or know what I could do to debug the issue?

Error

```
ERROR: A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.
The install of ciscojabbertest2 was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ciscojabbertest2\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
```

Below is a copy of my nuspec file and my chocolateyinstall.ps1 file.

ciscojabbertest2.nuspec

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2015/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ciscojabbertest2</id>
    <version>11.9.1.55716</version>
    <title>ciscojabbertest2</title>
    <authors>Cisco Systems, Inc</authors>
    <tags>Installer_MSI_Database</tags>
    <summary>Cisco Jabber</summary>
    <description>Cisco Jabber</description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="tools\**" target="tools" />
  </files>
</package>
```

chocolateyinstall.ps1

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';
$toolsDir   = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
$fileLocation = '\\WIN-5LEH3K6JCM3\Software_Test\CiscoJabberSetup.msi'

$packageArgs = @{
  packageName   = $env:ChocolateyPackageName
  unzipLocation = $toolsDir
  fileType      = 'MSI'
  $file         = $fileLocation

  softwareName  = 'Cisco Jabber*'

  checksum      = 'A027601E0975339286EEECF593D83FF71FA64902B46A8F10F93B5E63663A215F'
  checksumType  = 'sha256'

  silentArgs    = "/quiet CLEAR=1"
  validExitCodes= @(0, 3010, 1641)
}

Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage @packageArgs
```

Comment: This question has been added to https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting. It will be updated on the next deploy of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the error that you are seeing is due to the undefined variable `$file`.  As a result, you are getting a key in the hash literal that doesn't have any value.

Change it to the following:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';
$toolsDir        = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
$fileLocation    = '\\WIN-5LEH3K6JCM3\Software_Test\CiscoJabberSetup.msi'

$packageArgs = @{
  packageName    = $env:ChocolateyPackageName
  unzipLocation  = $toolsDir
  fileType       = 'MSI'
  file           = $fileLocation

  softwareName   = 'Cisco Jabber*'

  checksum       = 'A027601E0975339286EEECF593D83FF71FA64902B46A8F10F93B5E63663A215F'
  checksumType   = 'sha256'

  silentArgs     = "/quiet CLEAR=1"
  validExitCodes = @(0, 3010, 1641)
}

Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage @packageArgs
```